# Solidity event returns object instead of string

Tags: solidity, events, frontend, event-handling

I'm trying to test and learn how I can register a solidity event in front-end and get the value. everything seems to be fine except I get [object object] instead of the string and when I log the exact message I get a json file, something like this:

```
Indexed {_isIndexed: true, hash:'0x....'}
```

Here's my contract:

```
contract MyContract{
 string private sampleString;
 event getStringEv(string indexed msg);
 function getEvFn() public{
  emit getStringEv(sampleString);
 }
 function setsampleStringFn(string memory _msg) public{
 //code to set sampleString value
 }
}
```

And here's my front-end code:

```
async function registerEv(){
 if(typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(greeterAddress, Lock.abi, provider);
  contract.on("getStringEv", (mMsg) => {
   console.log("received event");
   console.log(mMsg); //which I get [object object] and not a string
  });
 }
```

I also tried mMsg.toString() with no success. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Are you new to JS as well? Try to json stringify `mMsg`, like `JSON.stringify(mMsg)`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've tried that. That just returns part of the json I was getting as string. I edited the question with the json I'm receiving.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I was missing was that indexed event parameters are stored as byte32 and to store a string as indexed parameter, Solidity hashes it and returns a hash. Removing "indexed" will return the string as supposed.